# Only first document is returned as response instead of multiple documents using Firestore and Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have this Express function:

```
exports.getSliderTipsteriData = (req, res) => {
  let sliderTipsteriData = [];
  db.collection("tipsterBanner")
    .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
    .where("show", "==", true)
    .get()
    .then((data) => {
      data.forEach((doc) => {
        let eventId = doc.data().eventId;
        sliderTipsteriData = doc.data();
        db.collection("evenimenteTipsteri")
          .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
          .get()
          .then((data) => {
            sliderTipsteriData.tipsteri = [];
            data.forEach((doc) => {
              if(doc.data().bilet[0].id === sliderTipsteriData.eventId) {
                sliderTipsteriData.tipsteri.push({
                  tipster: doc.data().tipster,
                  homeTeam: doc.data().bilet[0].homeTeam,
                  awayTeam: doc.data().bilet[0].awayTeam
                })
              } else null
            })
            return res.json(sliderTipsteriData);
          })
      })
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).json({ error: err.code });
    });
};
```

and received this as response:

```
{
    "imageUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/socialape-bea5b.appspot.com/o/slider1.jpg?alt=media&token=0824a93d-4bc3-49fa-9ae8-4408961a0736",
    "event_date": 1614110400,
    "awayTeamName": "Bayer Leverkusen",
    "awayTeamPercent": 23,
    "homeTeamName": "Atletico Madrid",
    "homeTeamShortName": "ATL",
    "awayTeamEmblem": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/34.png",
    "createdAt": "2021-03-22T18:25:03.667Z",
    "homeTeamEmblem": "https://media.api-sports.io/football/teams/49.png",
    "awayTeamShortName": "LEV",
    "homeTeamPercent": "77",
    "show": true,
    "eventId": 652238,
    "homeTeamColor": "#0099ff",
    "awayTeamColor": "#ff0000",
    "etapa": "Liga Campionilor, Etapa 2",
    "tipsteri": [
        {
            "tipster": "daniel",
            "homeTeam": "Lazio",
            "awayTeam": "Bayern Munich"
        },
        {
            "tipster": "user",
            "homeTeam": "Lazio",
            "awayTeam": "Bayern Munich"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I have more than one document in **tipsterBanner** collection, but I receive only the first one. So the forEach doc might not be working properly.

Any idea what I miss here?
I expect to receive as response the **sliderTipsteriData** array with multiple objects, not only the first one. Looks like the forEach actually doesn't loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have promises trying to run in loops that don't wait for them. Inside your `then` blocks, you perform more asynchronous calls (`collection().get()`) but your code isn't waiting for them to resolve, so it's just flying through your `forEach` loop, creating those promises, but then getting to the end and returning.

There are two ways to solve that problem - (1) put your `then/catch` calls into a `Promise.all` and wait for that to resolve or (2) switch to async/await. But I think you have an even better solution. Right now, you're querying your `evenimenteTipsteri` collection in each loop, but you're not using any information from the `tipsterBanner` collection as parameters in the `evenimenteTipsteri` query, so you could just query both of them one time and then handle all the filtering/organizing in code. This will help speed up your results *and* help protect you from the costs of unnecessary reads on Firestore.

This code is untested because I just copy/pasted your code and rewrote it without being able to run it, but this is the main idea:

```js
exports.getSliderTipsteriData = (req, res) => {
  let sliderTipsteriData = [];

  // These create the promises which will resolve in our Promise.all()
  const tipsterBanner = db.collection("tipsterBanner").orderBy("createdAt", "desc").where("show", "==", true).get()
  const evenimenteTipsteri = db.collection("evenimenteTipsteri").orderBy("createdAt", "desc").get()

  Promise.all([tipsterBanner, evenimenteTipsteri]).then((results) => {
    // results is now an array of your original "data" items from your then blocks
    // results[0] is the data from the tipsterBanner query
    // results[1] is the data from the evenimenteTipsteri query
    const tipsterBannerResults = results[0] // Just to make it more readable
    const evenimenteTipsteriResults = results[1] // Just to make it more readable
    tipsterBannerResults.forEach(doc => {
      let eventId = doc.data().eventId
      sliderTipsteriData = doc.data() // Is this right? You could end up overwriting your data
      sliderTipsteriData.tipsteri = []
      evenimenteTipsteriResults.forEach(doc => {
        if(doc.data().bilet[0].id === sliderTipsteriData.eventId) {
          sliderTipsteriData.tipsteri.push({
            tipster: doc.data().tipster,
            homeTeam: doc.data().bilet[0].homeTeam,
            awayTeam: doc.data().bilet[0].awayTeam
          })
        }
      })
    })
    return res.json(sliderTipsteriData)
  }).catch(error => {
    // Handle errors from your queries
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, the code actually works :) but I have the same result, if I have 2 collections with show = true, I got only one, no loop. I'm pretty sure I overwriting the data here sliderTipsteriData = doc.data()